# Flat design Java Swing Look and Feel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, look-and-feel

I am looking for a flat design Java Swing Look and Feel similar to recent Android or iOS UI.
Thanks in advance.
Gilles

Comment: you can create your custom look and feel (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html)

Answer (score 2):

Please see the [Java Tutorials on Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html). It will give you all the basic information you could want on Look and Feel.

- [Available Look and Feels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#available)
- [Programatically Setting the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#programmatic)
- [Specifying the Look and Feel: Command Line](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#commandLine)
- [Specifying the Look and Feel: swing.properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#properties)
- [How the UI Manager Chooses the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#steps)
- [Changing the Look and Feel After Startup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#dynamic)
- [An Example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#example)
- [Themes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#themes)